# JavaScript tab doesn't toggle on mobile but works fine on desktop

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I embedded a tab function on my website which seems to work on desktop fine but, when viewing the website on mobile the tab refuses to toggle. It only displays the default open tab but won't navigate to the other tab.

I will highly appreciate some help from anyone knowledgable in solving this issue. Here is my code!

```
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  let i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablink');
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = 'block';

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById('defaultOpen').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible another element on your webpage is getting the click event on mobile. To be sure, open your browser's developer tools, run in the console `window.addEventListener('click', e => {console.log(e.target)});` That will tell you what element got a click event.

Then, once you know what element got the event, you just need to figure out why. Possibly you need to make the clickable area of your tabs larger.

If you post a fully reproducible code sample, we can help you dive a little deeper! You could for instance use the html page creator in StackOverflow to reproduce just the tabs portion of your website, and we can help debug that part of the site...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the error after a few hours of debugging. The problem was with my style sheet. I was using left-float on the tab links instead of display-flex. Thanks for your input Duhaime, Well appreciated!